# How to edit categories in appointments?

Tags: vba, outlook

I have a macro that before sending any item, will pop-up the Categories dialog to assign one category if the outgoing item is a meeting appointment

If I open the appointment to edit it, I can see the category assigned in the top of the window but when the macro runs it can't detect that it already has a category assigned.

Why is `Item.Categories` empty on an appointment that has a category assigned?

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)

On Error Resume Next
  
  Dim objNS As NameSpace
  Dim objFolder As MAPIFolder
  Dim folder_assignat As String
  Dim olApptItem As Outlook.AppointmentItem
  
 'Check if item is an email
  If Item.Class <> olMail Then
    GoTo fin
  End If
   'Code to be applied in case is an email (check for attachments, etc...)
   '
   '
   '
Exit Sub

'jumps here in case item is not an email
fin:
If Item.Class = olMeetingRequest Then
     If Item.Categories = "" Then
       Item.ShowCategoriesDialog
     End If
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Application.ItemSent` event fires for the outgoing `MeetingItem` object, bot for its parent `AppointmentItem`.

Call `MeetingItem.GetAssociatedAppointment` to get the parent appointment.

Comment: Thank you Dmitry, that was the solution! I appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

Need to specify the True condition for the call

```
Set itempapa = Item.GetAssociatedAppointment(True)
If itempapa.Categories = "" Then
      Item.ShowCategoriesDialog
End If
```

Now the categories dialog only appears if meeting has no category assigned